# AWS secret rotated when updating stack on Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager

I have a Cloudformation script that calls several nested stacks such as one creating the database. I am first creating a secret in the secrets manager, and then using it in the database instance for the username and password. I don't want to have automated secret rotation enabled for now.

My problem is that every time I update the stack, it generates a new secret, which is not propagated to the database. So afterwards, when my updated ECS service tries to connect to the database, it is using the wrong password, so it cannot become stable and then everything has to be rolled back.

Why is my password rotated even if I haven't configured it to do so? Is there a way I can avoid this? If I cannot, should I add AWS::SecretsManager::SecretTargetAttachment in order to at least propagate the changes to the database?

```
DBSecret:
  Type: "AWS::SecretsManager::Secret"
  Properties:
    Name: !Join ['', [!Ref ProductName, '-', !Ref EnvironmentName, '-', !Ref DBName, '-db-secret']]
    Description: Secret to be used for the database 
    KmsKeyId: !Ref KmsKeyId
    GenerateSecretString:
      SecretStringTemplate: !Join ['', ['{"username": "', !Ref DBUser , '"}']]
      GenerateStringKey: "password"
      PasswordLength: 30
      ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\'
    Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join ['', [!Ref ProductName, '-', !Ref EnvironmentName, '-', !Ref DBName, '-db-secret']]

PostgresDb:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
  Properties:
    AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
    AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: 'true'
    VPCSecurityGroups:
      - Ref: SecurityGroup
    DBName: !Ref DBName
    DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBInstanceClass
    DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
    Engine: postgres
    EngineVersion: !Ref DBVersion
    MasterUsername: !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref DBSecret , ':SecretString:username}}']]
    MasterUserPassword: !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref DBSecret , ':SecretString:password}}']]
    MultiAZ: !Ref DBMultiAZ
    StorageType: gp2
    BackupRetentionPeriod: 7
    StorageEncrypted: !Ref DBEncrypted
    # Only add the KMS key if the db is going to be encrypted
    KmsKeyId: !If [IsEncrypted, !Ref KmsKeyId, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
    MonitoringInterval: !If [HasEnhancedMonitoring, !Ref DBEnhancedMonitoringInterval, "0"]
    MonitoringRoleArn: !If [HasEnhancedMonitoring, !Ref DBMonitoringRoleARN, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
    Port: 5432

    Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Ref DBIdentifier
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to separate your data base and db configuration in a separate Stack. Data Base infrastructure and db password is not something you will update often, while your code will be in a continuos lifecycle of changes. Your ECS services can reference your password from the other stack using Fn::ImportValue. Check the docs here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html

Comment: I know this is possible, but I chose to work with nested stacks because I have created templates as mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html e.g. for database creation to avoid code duplication (e.g. 
I need 2 databases for each application instance and I need to create new instances all the time using the same CF file (that references all these templates) so it would be a nightmare to work with so may outputted values. But I am confused why you say my code will change all the time, this is my infra, not my application code

Comment: I said that because when you deploy code, it is really common to apply bug fixes, new releases, make changes, etc, whereas your database configuration won't change most likely. From your CF you are not supposed to deploy code, but you may run into the case of having the need of updating your infra for your app, then you will need to tier down and spin up new servers, which implies in new deployments of code. All these will occur while your data base remains untouchable.

Comment: Anyway, I am kind of surprised that every time you apply a Stack Update, your `DBSecret ` gets updated. Are you sure you are not changing the YML right? Also, instead of Update Stack, can you first create a Change Set to see all the changes that will be applied? Look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets-create.html